# Top 100 youtube videos

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Is there any way to have updated lists of top 100 videos of youtube by genre and/or by country!

Any kind of resources like json files or xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the `chart` parameter of the videos.list endpoint. Set the `chart` to mostPopular, and then include a `regionCode` parameter and `videoCategoryId` parameter for further narrowing down. For example,

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&chart=mostPopular&regionCode=UA&key={YOUR_API_KEY`}

Will retrieve the 5 most popular videos in the Ukraine.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&chart=mostPopular&maxResults=25&regionCode=DE&videoCategoryId=1&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Will retrieve the 25 most popular videos in Germany that relate to Film/Animation. And so on.

Note that if you don't include a videoCategoryId parameter, it will return results from all categories. If you don't include a regionCode, it returns the most popular videos across all regions. You can only set videoCategoryId to a value that's valid in the region you're searching in (you can use the videoCategories.list endpoint to find valid categories for regions, languages, etc.)